# best way to get a specific object from and array without looping

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In one of the controllers of my angular application i have a variable set as follows.

```
SomeService.get({}, function(data){
    // this sets xyz as the list of the data retrieved 
    // from the resource within the controllers scope
    $scope.xyz = data.objects;    
});
```

Now `$scope.xyz` looks something like

```
[
    0: {id: 1, ...more data here ...},
    1: {id: 2, ...more data here ...},
    2: {id: 3, ...more data here ...},
    3: {id: 4, ...more data here ...},
    4: {id: 5, ...more data here ...},
    5: {id: 6, ...more data here ...},
]
```

What i am trying to do is get an object within xyz using the `id` property (not the list index). I am aware that I can iterate over the array as follows.

```
angular.forEach($scope.xyz, function(obj){ return obj.id == 1;});
```

but is there a way I can do it without looping over the list ?

Comment: Check the answer to [this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-array-of-javascript-objects) The recommendation is to use the jQuery [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) function.

Comment: Are you trying to go without underscore/lo-dash or similar utility belts?

Comment: @Stewie well I am open to options, but it would be good if there is a way without depending on a lib for such a small use case.

Comment: Well, Angular does not try to offer such low-level utilities, so this question is all about JavaScript solution for loop-less mapping. For that matter I'd say @Bergi answer is the best you can expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't really avoid looping (`O(n)`) unless there are some preconditions met.

- If the array is sorted by id, you can use a binary search algorithm (`O(log n)`).
- If the array index always corresponds to the id-1 (or some similar simple formula), you can directly access it in `O(1)`.

If those conditions are not fulfilled initially, but you need to access the items by id multiple times, it could be helpful to bring them in that form (sorting/building a hash map).

Answer (score 8):

Though this is already answered a year ago, since this is one of the top results in Google, I thought I can add the following suggestion which may be the easiest way to filter. 
After injecting $filter into your controller,

```
var result = $filter('filter')($scope.xyz, {id:"1"});
```

reference: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter