# How to efficiently merge two arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

Lets say I've got two arrays of objects in Javascript:

```
var myList = [{id: 3, info: 'bla'}, {id: 97, info: 'ble'}, {id: 25, info: 'blu'}];
var newList = [{id: 5, info: 'blo'}, {id: 3, info: 'different Info!!'}];
```

I now want to "merge" the `newList` into `myList`, in the sense that:

- all objects with an id already present in `myList`, should be replaced by the object in `newList`
- all objects with an id not present in `myList`, should be added from `newList` to `myList`

I don't understand however, how I can check if an object with a certain id is already in the array. I guess you could do a loop over myList for every item in newList, but that is not very scalable.

Does anybody know how I can efficiently do this? All tips are welcome!

Comment: keep track of it when you create the array using a flag - otherwise you'd have to loop

Comment: Do an initial loop on one of the arrays and create a new object using the id as the key ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15411635/1048572

Comment: i think this link might help you

   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334660/combining-javascript-objects-into-one/1334710#1334710

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
function combineArray(array1, array2) {
    var arr = array1.concat(array2);

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        for(var j = i + 1; j < arr.length; ++j) {
            if(arr[i].id === arr[j].id)
                arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }

    return arr;
};
```

Then

```
combineArray([{id: 3, info: 'bla'}, {id: 97, info: 'ble'}, {id: 25, info: 'blu'}], [{id: 5, info: 'blo'}, {id: 3, info: 'different Info!!'}] );
```

returns

`[Object { id=97, info="ble"}, Object { id=25, info="blu"}, Object { id=5, info="blo"}, Object { id=3, info="different Info!!"}]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object to make sure the ID's are unique, and that would automatically overwrite the existing ID's, and then convert it back to an array

```js
var myList  = [{id: 5, info: 'bla'}, {id: 97, info: 'ble'}, {id: 25, info: 'blu'}];
var newList = [{id: 5, info: 'blo'}, {id: 3, info: 'different Info!!'}];
    
var o      = {};
var newArr = [];
    
myList.forEach(function(x) {
    o[x.id] = x;
});
    
newList.forEach(function(x) {
    o[x.id] = x;
});
    
for (var key in o) {
    newArr.push(o[key])
}

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(newArr, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to say that you will have to do some sort of itteration to compare your ID's.
You could Do an itteration over the first array of objects to get the ID attribute of every element. Inside this itteration you could do another itteration over the merging array comparing values and push your desired values to a new "result" array.

Maybe this could help you to keep your code tidy with the nested itterations:

[Find a value in an array of objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462318/find-a-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the `newList` checking if `myList` has the object with such id. If it does, replace the old one with a new using `splice`, otherwise push new object into `myList`.

```js
var myList = [{id: 3, info: 'bla'}, {id: 97, info: 'ble'}, {id: 25, info: 'blu'}];
var newList = [{id: 5, info: 'blo'}, {id: 3, info: 'different Info!!'}];

newList.forEach(function(el) {

    var found = myList.filter(function(obj) {
        return obj.id == el.id;
    });

    if (found.length) {
        myList.splice(myList.indexOf(found[0]), 1, el);
    }
    else {
        myList.push(el);
    }
});

alert( JSON.stringify(myList, null, '\t') );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.prototype.concat()` and `array.prototype.filter()` methods for this..

```
var myList = [{id: 3, info: 'bla'}, {id: 97, info: 'ble'}, {id: 25, info: 'blu'}];
var newList = [{id: 5, info: 'blo'}, {id: 3, info: 'different Info!!'}];
var temp = {};
var output = newList.concat(myList).filter(function(v){
    if (temp[v.id]){
        return false;
    }
    temp[v.id] = true;
    return true;
});

console.log(output);
```